Raspberry Pi 5 Not Booting up, Red LED Blinking No Green LED
I am powering my Raspberry Pi 5 through the GPIO pins using a Buck Converter that provides a 5V/5A output. I connected the converter's +5V output to the 5V GPIO pin and the ground (GND) to the corresponding GND pin on the Pi.
For serial communication with another device, I am using GPIO pins 14 (Tx) and 15 (Rx), and I ensured that the Pi's GND is connected to the GND of the device I'm communicating with. Based on my understanding, the communication wiring seems correct.
Everything worked fine for a couple of days, but the Pi suddenly stopped working. Now, only the red LED blinks, and there’s no green LED activity. According to documentation, a blinking red LED indicates that the input voltage is below 4.6V.
Initially, I powered my Raspberry Pi 5 using the original 5V/3A adapter, and it worked perfectly. After switching to the Buck Converter, it worked fine for a few days but then suddenly crashed. This is my second Pi 5 that has stopped working for some reason.
With the previous Pi 5, a similar issue occurred. Initially, the red LED was blinking, but after some time, it turned solid red. Additionally, the PMIC (Power Management IC) chip overheated every time that Pi was powered on.
In this current Pi, while the red LED is blinking, the PMIC chip is not overheating so far. The connections used for both Pi's were identical.
What could be the issue and how to resolve it.
UPDATED : I checked using multi meter that my 5V rail and 3.3V rail are short circuited with GND
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/pBFYcpxf.jpg
Buck Converter Link:
https://kitsguru.com/products/ubec-bec-5v-5a-input-2s-to-8s?srsltid=AfmBOorRjnVwaFizNcNL-3ILYTe3sOimTtmKWWDHGYl6pGjb_v4mTpjE

If you continue to connect dodgy power to the Pi expect to blow up a few more. PMIC have a very low tolerance for overvoltage.

I am using a buck converter that outputs 5V. I confirmed it on multiple instances. Can you please explain the wrong step in my process? The Pi kept working fine for 3-4 days and one day stopped while a process was running on it.

Link the specification of the buck converter. What is the serial device? Is it using 3.3V serial?

I Uploaded the Buck Converter picture in my original question. The buck converter is LM2596s. The serial device is PixHawk 1 ( Flight Controller ). I am using telemetry port 1 of PixHawk to communicate with Pi. from 6 pins of telemetry i am only using 3 which are Rx, Tx and GND.

Have you got a link to the buck converter you bought?

https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/520535/TI1/LM2596S-5.0.html

@HFK the link belongs in the question,  not in a comment

Looks like the wrong chip, you said 5A. That chip also appears adjustable is yours? Have you got a link to the board not the chip? Have you got an oscilloscope to measure the voltage?

My buck converter is not adjustable; it has a fixed output of 5V/5A. I couldn’t find a link to the specifications for my buck converter board, but I added a link in the question to the source where I purchased it. Unfortunately, I don’t have an oscilloscope to check if any transients are being generated by the buck converter.

" my 5V rail and 3.3V rail are short circuited with GND " is nonsense. If you connect them this is a guaranteed way to kill a Pi.

UBEC are normally quality devices BUT are NOT designed to provide a stable well regulated voltage suitable for powering a Pi.

I measured the resistance between 3.3V and GND, and between 5V and GND, while my Raspberry Pi was powered off. The resistance was around 0.1 ohms for both.
I understand your point regarding the UBEC. Can you suggest how I can power my Raspberry Pi safely? I'm building a quadcopter and i am using a 12V (5200mAh) LiPo battery (3S).

With a fully charged battery what does the buck converter output voltage read with a multimeter?

@CoderMike 4.97 Volts at Fully Charged Battery

Measuring voltage with a multimeter is a waste of time. If LOW, as this appears to be (normal supply voltage is 5.1V), does indicate an INADEQUATE supply but only a dynamic test with a CRO (or meter which records Min/Max). It is difficult to understand WHY you would put a Pi5 on a copter, but it is UNLIKELY to need 5A; indeed unless using many USB peripherals they run on a 1A supply.

@Milliways what alternative way do you suggest to measure the voltage across the terminals of my buck converter? Also, can you give hints of what went wrong? Also, I want to know if powering up pi from GPIO pins unsafe as compared to powering through type-c port? Thank you!

You can measure voltage with a professional grade meter, you can monitor transients with a CRO (preferably storage). This seems futile; you can measure till hell freezes over but if a simple static voltage measurement is low nothing will make it work. It makes no difference whether you use USB-C or pins 4,6 except if using a proper USB PD supply the Pi will be notified if it can supply 5A.
